# OpenLayers need advice on how to draw map features that can be visually highlighted

Tags: openlayers

I'm a relative newbie to OpenLayers.  My app involves displaying discrete GPS points on a map.  So far I've been doing this with OpenLayers.Feture.Vector objects, added to a VectorLayer using addFeatures, and the VectorLayer has a style. Also, each of the GPS points needs to have some metadata like name, datetime, etc., I'm using attributes for this. This works fine so far for simply displaying the points.

But one requirement I have is the ability to visually highlight at times a single, particular feature, probably by changing it's color.  I cannot figure out how to do this with my current approach.  Should I be using Markers instead?  Can markers also have attributes?

Thanks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend looking into [StyleMaps](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/feature_styling.html). There you can define how a feature should look in different states, for example "selected". The style could be set in different colors, sizes or icons.

When you select a feature, either by a user action or programmatically, the features will conform to your "select-style"

Comment: Thanks, reading up on StyleMaps now.  I don't want to change the style of an feature just when i hover over it -- I also will want to change the feature when an event happens elsewhere in the dom, e.g. hovering over something else.  I'll be interested to see if it can support that requirement.  thanks again.

Comment: Ok, I think it'a good thing to use this approach and then focusing on getting the "select-sync" going between your other markup and the OpenLayers features. This way you separate the functionality and let OL do with details like deselecting and such.